# How can i make an falling object do not get affected by another objects when intersect in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Ok, so i have OBJ A an falling object. OBJ B is like a coin...and i want to colect it. When intersecting these 2 objects. obj b affects falling speed/trajectory of obj a..

I'm using this:

`- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact`

How can i make when intersecting "obj b" with "obj a" do not affect falling speed or trajectory of "obj a"?

This  is "obj a":

```
        ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"theShip"];
    ship.name=@"ship";
    ship.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    ship.size=CGSizeMake(100, 50);
    ship.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(myWorld.frame), 0);
    ship.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:50];
    ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ship.frame.size.width * 0.5];
    ship.physicsBody.allowsRotation=NO;
    ship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=shipCategory;
    ship.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = coinCategory | padCategory;
```

And this is "obj b":

```
Coin *node = [Coin node];
[node setPosition:position];
[node setName:@"node_coin"];

[node setCoinType:coinType];
SKSpriteNode *sprite;
if (coinType == COIN_NORMAL) {
    sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
} else if (coinType == COIN_DOUBLE){
    sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
}else if (coinType == COIN_TRIPLE){
    sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

}
[node addChild:sprite];

node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=NO;

node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinCategory;
node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
```

I've attached an image to make this more clear..

[image]

Comment: What did you set ``collisionBitMask`` of ObjA and ObjB physics bodies to?

Comment: ring ring :), yes this solved my little newbie problem. Thank you very much. Can you write this as an answer? It may help somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: `collisionBitMask` is set to `0xFFFFFFFF` (i.e., all bits set - thanks 0x141E) by default.

This means that *ObjA* will collide with every object that has its `physicsBody`set.

**Solution**: set `collisionBitMask` of *ObjA* to something different than 0.

*collisionBitMask definition*:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) uint32_t collisionBitMask;
```

Comment: The collision bit mask is not 0 by default. It's 0xFFFFFFFF (i.e., all bits set), so it collides with everything.

Comment: @0x141E That's correct. Totally missed that. I'll update the answer.